# SQL - Compute difference between two rows and put in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an MySQL table that contains a date, a source, a number of e.g. facebook fans and a third column, which should contain the change to the previous day.

The table looks like this:

```
Date        |  Source  | fans | new fans
2013-02-02  | Facebook | 100  | -
2013-02-02  | Twitter  | 60   | -
2013-02-03  | Facebook | 120  | -
2013-02-03  | Twitter  | 62   | -
2013-02-04  | Twitter  | 65   | -
2013-02-04  | Facebook | 130  | -
2013-02-05  | Facebook | 145  | -
2013-02-05  | Twitter  | 70   | -
```

and

the sql query should turn it into this:

```
Date        |  Source  | fans | new fans
2013-02-02  | Facebook | 100  | - 
2013-02-02  | Twitter  | 60   | - 
2013-02-03  | Facebook | 120  | 20
2013-02-03  | Twitter  | 62   | 2 
2013-02-04  | Twitter  | 65   | 3 
2013-02-04  | Facebook | 130  | 10
2013-02-05  | Facebook | 145  | 15
2013-02-05  | Twitter  | 70   | 5
```

How can I compute the difference between two days for a source?

Comment: Correct people will look into your question if you tag it correctly (than saying it mysql in the description). Just like @bluefeet did.

Comment: Can you guarantee that there will be a record for **every** day (after the first day) for each source? Do you actually want to update the table, or do you just want to present the results as the output from a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using an `UPDATE JOIN`; `a` and `b` being the two rows to calculate the difference between, and `c` being LEFT joined in to make sure there's no row between `a` and `b`.

```
UPDATE TableA AS a
JOIN TableA b 
  ON a.`Source` = b.`Source` AND a.`Date` > b.`Date`
LEFT JOIN TableA c
  ON a.`Source` = c.`Source` AND a.`Date` > c.`Date` AND c.`Date` > b.`Date`
SET a.`new fans` = a.`fans` - b.`fans`
WHERE c.`Date` IS NULL
```

[An SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11a69/2)

Note that this will *UPDATE THE DATA IN YOUR TABLE* and you should always back up before running SQL updates from random people on the Internet :)

Comment: Works perfectly, even if a day is missing in between. Thanks a lot.